# Creating a specific chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I would like to create a chart like this: http://take.ms/BEie1.

[image]

The first two columns are the name and serial number.

I have to put these two on the X axis as in the images, and the Y axis is for the percentage usage.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
Dim xRange As Range
Dim yRange As Range
Dim objCht As ChartObject

Set objCht = detailsh.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=detailsh.Columns("A").Left, Width:=350, Top:=detailsh.Rows(9).Top, Height:=210)
Set xRange = Range("I2:J9")
Set xRange = Range("L2:L9")

With objCht.Chart
    Set srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With srs
        .name = detailsh.Range("B1")
        .Values = detailsh.Range("I2:I7")
        .XValues = detailsh.Range("L2:L7")
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it finally :) 
Here is my code, maybe it can help for anyone else.

```
Dim sourcech As Chart
Set sourcech = Charts.Add
Set sourcech = sourcech.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, name:="Details")

With sourcech
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Details").Range("l2:L9")
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Details").Range("I2:J9") 'here you can modify the X axes

End With
```